# How do I use an ANSI sequence to signify progress in Windows Terminal using Bash?

Tags: bash, powershell, windows-terminal

PowerShell has a [`Write-Progress` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.3) that would update the Terminal icon to indicate progress.

I would like to do the same in Bash (and *NOT* exec powershell)

I think it is doable from the link

> PowerShell displays certain information using ANSI escape sequences

So I was wondering what those ANSI sequences are.

[image]

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to remove "powershell" from the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escape sequence is [`ESC ] 9 ; 4 ; st ; pr ST`](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/8055).

`pr` is the current progress. `st` can be one of the following:

| Value | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Clear the progress indicator |
| 1 | Set the progress to `pr` % |
| 2 | Set the progress to `pr` % in error state |
| 3 | Set the progress indicator to indeterminate state |
| 4 | Set the progress to `pr` % in warning state |

For example,

```bash
# Show indeterminate indicator for a couple seconds.
echo -en "\e]9;4;3;0\e\\"
sleep 3

# Run normally up to 40 %.
for i in {10..40..10}
do
    echo -en "\e]9;4;1;$i\e\\"
    sleep 1
done

# Continue in error state for a couple seconds.
for i in {50..70..10}
do
    echo -en "\e]9;4;2;$i\e\\"
    sleep 1
done

# Continue in warning state for a couple seconds.
for i in {80..100..10}
do
    echo -en "\e]9;4;4;$i\e\\"
    sleep 1
done

# Clear progress indicator.
echo -en "\e]9;4;0;0\e\\"
```

Comment: Where can we find all escape sequences regarding Windows Terminal? Thanks!

Comment: @Philippe I'm not aware of any comprehensive documentation existing anywhere (other than the source code itself).